# adding a new combobox item on top not from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

I have declared this `ComboBox`:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"  
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" MaxLength="0"  DataTextField="kompania" DataValueField="kompania"

            style="display: inline;position: static;"  >
             <asp:ListItem Text="Mild" Value="0" />

            </ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:bootstrap1 %>" 

            SelectCommand="SELECT [idkompania], [kompania] FROM [kompania] ORDER BY [kompania]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

So it basically takes its values from a database table. What i want to do now is to add a new item on the top of the `ComboBox`, because i have to additionally process that item programatically. I have tried to add a new `ListItem`, but it doesn't display... any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add that item in codeBehind file?

Here is the code :

```
YourComboBoxName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("ExtraItem", "-1"));
```

In above line of code 0 means the position at which you want to add this Item.

ExtraItem is the Text to display and -1 should be the selectedValue when Item is selected.

Comment: already trie that. it works as long as you do not have any query binded with the previous items of the combobox. in the moment you add a sqldatasource, it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this scenario for [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) RadComboBox and I solve it like bellow:
You can do it by adding your item on DataBound event of combobox:

```
protected void testComboBox_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var combo = (RadComboBox)sender;
     combo.Items.Insert(0, new RadComboBoxItem("My First Test Item", string.Empty));
}
```

Comment: still not working. Error: Unable to cast object of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox'.

Comment: Your cast isn't correct! you are trying to cast Item of type AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox to System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox and it is not correct. you should have something like this: var combo = (AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox) sender;